# PostgreSQL storing paths for reference in scripts

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to find the appropriate place to store a system path in PostgreSQL.

What I'm trying to do is load values into a table using the COPY command. However, since I will be referring to the same file path regularly I want to store that path in one place. I've tried creating a function to return the appropriate path, but I get a syntax error when I call the function in the COPY command. I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it, but I'll post my code anyway.

COPY command:

```
COPY employee_scheduler.countries (code, name)
    FROM get_csv_path('countries.csv')
    WITH CSV;
```

Function Definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    employee_scheduler.get_csv_path(IN file_name VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(250) AS $$
DECLARE
    path VARCHAR(200) := E'C:\\Brian\\Work\\employee_scheduler\\database\\csv\\';
    file_path VARCHAR(250) := '';
BEGIN
   file_path := path || file_name;
   RETURN file_path;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If anyone has a different idea on how to accomplish this I'm open to suggestions.

UPDATE:

The error I am receiving is:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "employee_scheduler"
LINE 12:     FROM employee_scheduler.get_csv_path('countries.csv')

I've tried the following statements with no luck:

```
COPY employee_scheduler.countries (code, name)
    FROM employee_scheduler.get_csv_path('countries.csv')
    WITH CSV;

COPY employee_scheduler.countries (code, name)
    FROM (employee_scheduler.get_csv_path('countries.csv'))
    WITH CSV;

COPY employee_scheduler.countries (code, name)
    FROM (SELECT * FROM employee_scheduler.get_csv_path('countries.csv'))
    WITH CSV;
```

I'm beginning to think the way I'm trying to achieve this isn't possible. Does anyone else have any ideas on how to achieve this? I might just have to hard code the path everywhere if I want to use the copy statement...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not a right WAY. Calling Function in Copy Command is not going to help.

Create a function a as given below to make it workable:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUnction copy_data(filename text) returns int
as
$$
declare
cmd text;
Begin
cmd:='copy test_copy from '||''''||get_csv(filename)||''''||' with delimiter '||''''||','||''''||';';
execute cmd
return 1;
End;
$$ language plpgsql;

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine.  However, you need to say `employee_scheduler.get_csv_path('countries.csv')` instead of just `get_csv_path('countries.csv')` (unless I'm mistaken).  Try this in psql and make sure it works:

```
=> SELECT employee_scheduler.get_csv_path('countries.csv');
                        get_csv_path                         
-------------------------------------------------------------
 C:\Brian\Work\employee_scheduler\database\csv\countries.csv
(1 row)
```

Comment: Ya, I tried adding the employee_scheduler.get_csv_path before and it still doesn't work. It does produce the correct output, with the select statement, but doesn't work in the COPY statement. I've updated my question with the error I'm receiving, as well as the different things I have tried.